# Regex capture group extracting elements of a list in a sentence

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, regex

I have a list of sentences, with some that contain elements in sentence list form:

| index | sentence |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | You can get cars, trucks, planes, and boats. |
| 1 | You can get the car, truck, and plane. |
| 2 | You should ignore this sentence. |

I only wish to extract elements from sentences that start with "You can get" or "You can get the" which I hope to extract using pandas `extractall` [method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html), where I extract each individual element of the list in the sentences.

Desired output:

| index | match | object |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | car |
|  | 1 | truck |
|  | 2 | plane |
|  | 3 | boat |
| 1 | 0 | car |
|  | 1 | truck |
|  | 2 | plane |

I have three main questions:

1. How to use look behinds `(?<=[Y|y]ou can get )` so it won't capture `the`
2. How to include the look ahead `\w+(?=s)?` so that both plural and singular forms of the elements are captured
3. Is it possible to write a capture group that also extracts each word as individual elements, or should I extract the list in the sentence first (e.g `cars, trucks, planes, and boats`) then run another regex?

Comment: Note, words like `analysis, basis, bias, crisis, diagnosis, mathematics, civics, physics etc.` are singulars ending with `s`.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I have confirmed that all possibilities of the actual elements I'm extracting instead of the toy examples above do not end in `s`. Nonetheless, thanks for the note as I did not catch that myself haha

Comment: so you need to extract all words whether they ending with `s` or not cause there's no assurance if its singular or plular

Comment: Using [PyPI regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) e.g. [`^(?!You can get).+(*SKIP)(*F)|\b\pL+?(?=s?[,.])`](https://regex101.com/r/3zGNu1/2) ([Python demo](https://tio.run/##VY9Na8MwDIbP9a/QfLLb4MvOJbfBaAuDncaygZtoiWkqG1uBFvbfM/Xj0J1eSTwPktKZh0jP8xyOKWaGjD2ewBcplLo1a8j629RPH3GC1hP0yNatzPJ98/pmzfLF/jb7Jm1XtanXpf6s3JfVShXxFkY/SJK5VMB5ag@SafSEkp462EfPxTWk1eKfwQNerLt0Y6/eA1uGOI0dhJ5iRjFCgYLESC06bZU6em4HvJyT0f0E6vw4mutnFch6Ge6ESjkQmztr5/kP))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using:

```
df.loc[df['sentence'].str.startswith('You can get '),
       'sentence'].str.extractall(r'(?P<object>\S+?)s?\b(?:,|.$)')
```

Output:

```
        object
  match       
0 0        car
  1      truck
  2      plane
  3       boat
1 0        car
  1      truck
  2      plane
```

Answer (score 2):

A more reliable way is to filter the rows which start with `"You can get "`, then replace optional `the` article, possible `and/or` conjunctions and extract the remaining words:

```
(df[df['sentence'].str.startswith('You can get ')]['sentence']
 .str.replace(r'\b(You can get |the|and|or)\b', '', regex=True)
 .str.extractall(r'(\w+)'))
```

---

```
             0
  match        
0 0        cars
  1      trucks
  2      planes
  3       boats
1 0         car
  1       truck
  2       plane
```

Answer (score 1):

1. I think you should filter all the sentences that match the first condition ([Y|y]ou can get)
   Then you can try using regex to extract all the needed parts.
2. `((?:car|truck|plane|boat|box|basis)(?:\w+(?=s|es)?)?)` You can try this to capture in singular and plural form, but you must predefined your list of words to capture.
   tested sentence: *You can get cars, trucks, planes, and boats, box, basis*

Comment: That means you should know in advance the words to extract

Comment: yep, I assume he only want to extract some specific words